# HTML5 track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute

Tags: html, amazon-s3, cross-domain, html5-video

I have MP4 video file and WEBVTT file both stored in my AWS S3.
The AWS S3 bulk configured to my subdomain, and can access it through: http://clip.mydomain.com/bulkname/video.mp4

My web application location: http://dev.mydomain.com/index.html

When I load the page, I try to load my video and track element:

```
<video id="Video." controls  width="100%" height="90%" style="padding-top: 30px;height: 90%;">
<source src="http://clip.mydomain.com/bulkname/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<track kind="metadata" label="GetAlert metadata" src="http://clip.mydomain.com/bulkname/video.trk" srclang="en" default></track>
</video>
```

I get the following cross domain error:

> Text track from origin 'http://clip.mydomain.com' has been blocked
>   from loading: Not at same origin as the document, and parent of track
>   element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute. Origin
>   'http://dev.mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

My bulk configured to support cross domain (
CORS Configuration), which seems like I gave access, I tried also without "http://":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://clip.mydomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://dev.mydomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: CORS config seems legit, but consider `parent of track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute.`...  It seems like one of your tags needs `crossorigin="anonynmous"` or *something along those lines*.  I'm speculating rather wildly,  but that's what the error seems to be saying.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot this is indeed the case. But even adding the attribute does not guarantee access as the server can refuse the request.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Sure, the server "can" refuse the request -- but it won't.  It's your server. The problem you have right now is that the browser, itself, is *refusing to ask* for the resource.  It isn't asking and being denied.

Comment: I add crossorigin="anonynmous" to video element but receive the following error:
Redirect at origin 'http://clips.mydomain.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dev.mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot see Josephs comment above for the answer to that.

Comment: Oops, sorry @K3N I apparently got you and OP confused.  Now, it seems, we have a real, actual CORS configuration issue.  Or...

Comment: "Redirect at origin `clips.mydomain.com`?"  What's "clips" (with an "s" at the end) and how did it get introduced into the mix, here?  Is there a redirect in the path that isn't mentioned in the question?

Comment: Typo?  This is copy/paste.  I'm not sure I fully accept that explanation.  Your question still shows it without an "s" in the CORS configuration.  We need a question that accurately represents the actual situation you're trying to solve, or we are all wasting time.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  THE typo is ONLY in my last comment, of course not in the configuration!!!  The question and the issue remain the same, the typo only in my last comment!  - it is: clip.mydomain.com WITHOUT "s"

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, you mistyped `anonymous` and @Joseph added it as is with the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to `<video>` tag:

```
<video id="Video." crossorigin="anonymous" controls  width="100%" height="90%" style="padding-top: 30px;height: 90%;">
<source src="http://clip.mydomain.com/bulkname/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<track kind="metadata" label="GetAlert metadata" src="http://clip.mydomain.com/bulkname/video.trk" srclang="en" default></track>
</video>
```

See also [doc on crossorigin attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes)

Comment: I used to add this attribute to the Track tag but it is not enough it should be added to the video tag as you mentioned.